# Get text from an unfocused file in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I need to get the text from a given URI in VSCode for developing my extension.

If you have a focused file you can easily do

```
document.getText()
```

and that would be it, but I need to get the text from a path.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`vscode.workspace.fs`](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_37#_vscodeworkspacefs) API that was introduced in the most recent 1.37 release. More specifically the [`readFile()`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FileSystem.readFile) method:

> ```ts
> readFile(uri: Uri): Thenable<Uint8Array>
> ```
>
> Read the entire contents of a file.

The regular Node `fs` API will also work, but doesn't account for some VSCode features such as remote development or file system providers.

Comment: One note worth calling out here, if you were using a previous version of `vscode` note that when updating you need to take care to also run `npm install @types/vscode` otherwise you'll likely have type errors when trying to reference `vscode.workspace.fs`.

Comment: What is Thenable<Uint8Array> and how the heck do I convert that to a string?

Answer (score 0):

var buf = new Buffer('BUFFER OBJECT');
console.log(buf.toString());

so you can use

```
fs.readFile(uri).then(res => {
  console.log(res.toString());
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
FileSaver.readFile(fileUri.path, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(data);
        });
```